# Android: ImageButton with drawable resources throws ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to create my own button style by following [this instruction](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/). So I created two drawables (shapes). One for the pressed-style and one for the normal-style. Both just defer in the color.

But when I start the app, it crashes with the exception (see below). Somehow it can't find the button resource. But why?

That's the drawable shape (button_rounded_pressed.xml and button_rounded_normal.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    <padding android:left="7dp"
             android:top="7dp"
             android:right="7dp"
             android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Then I created a selector button_rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_rounded_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_rounded_normal" />
</selector>
```

And then use this style/drawable/selector on an ImageButton like this:

```
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
            />
```

But running the application throws the following exception when inflating the layout.

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/button_rounded.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02003b
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
>               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
>               at android.view.View.(View.java:3328)

**Note:** You can access my code [via GitHub](https://github.com/Nagilo1/MyToolbar).

Comment: I have downloaded your project from Github. It works correctly.

Comment: I cloned the project and it still crashes on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're testing on a pre-Lollipop device. You need to remove the `colorPrimary` attribute.

**EDIT:** As per [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251) bug report, referencing theme attributes in drawables wasn't supported until Lollipop.

Comment: True, now it works. But at the same time it's worthless, because I would like to use the color which is defined in the AppStyle.

Comment: @Matthias It's a bug present in pre-Lollipop devices. Theme attributes can't be referenced in drawables. Check this out https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251.